# Django + Neural Network

Tags: python, django, neural-network

I have web-application written on Django, and i am using Neural Network in it. Separately they works perfect, but together they work very strange.

So, here is the code :

1) settings.py

```
verifier = None
```

2) views.py

```
class SecurityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    Contains information about inputs/outputs of a single program
    that may be used in Universe workflows.
    '''
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)


    def authorize_person(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if(settings.verifier is None):
            return Response("Train first!",
                            status=400)

        X, y = load_data(140)
        x = np.array([X[0]])
        settings.verifier.load_networks()
        print settings.verifier.verify(x)

        return Response()

    def train_model(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        X, y = load_data(140)
        X, y, encoder = select_data_from_range_classes(X, y, range(0, 10))

        if(settings.verifier is None):
            print "Not initialized"
            settings.verifier = Verifier(X, y, encoder, 10)
            settings.verifier.train()
            x = np.array([X[0]])
            print settings.verifier.verify(x)

        else:
            print "Initialized"
            settings.verifier.X = X
            settings.verifier.y = y
            settings.verifier.encoder = encoder
            settings.verifier.train()
            settings.verifier.train()
        return Response()
```

So, what is the best way to store verifier object?To prevent re-initializing it every time? All functions works well in desktop project, but works strange in API-service. After some test i identified that its related with lifecycle of this object.

Comment: In Django, every request reinitialises the application state, so your verifier is being reset to None. Your line `settings.verifier = Verifier(X, y, encoder, 10)` doesn't change anything for future requests.You need some persistent storage, but there are many ways to achieve that and it depends on the `Verifier` object and how it works. You might look into memory cache, database storage, or session storage.

Comment: @ChidG, i am using tensor flow, and i have errors even when recreating object in every request, and trying to load weights(

Comment: Then go ahead and ask questions about those errors specifically. Have you looked at this? https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/. I'm not an expert but I suspect your design of initialising and training a neural network directly in a web request is a bad pattern. You may consider training the network in a scheduled task or offline process and simply serving the results via Django.